# Scene change on Cardboard / iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I've used the line:

SceneManager.LoadScene ("SceneRoom", LoadSceneMode.Single);

to go to the next scene on the start function along with:

using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

It works fine when I run it in Unity, but when I build it for my phone, it freezes before going to the next scene. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Try to make a test with some buttons to load different scenes, one scene exactly like the one who freezes, other one only with a cardboard set up, other with using some librarys etc. And see what is causing trouble.
Also, what are u doing exactly in the next scene? We need more information if possible

Comment: Thank you for your response! 

I've tried different tests. I have the scene change on a Rigidbody FPC. The next scene I've just added a cube as a platform and a new Rigidbody FPC. The code is in the Ridigbody FPC so it's reused.

I've tried doing it so it only happens if the scene is "startingscene" and when a raycast hits a specific object that only exists in the first scene.

Comment: My app crashes when trying a scene change. The newest cardboard says it fixes scene changing but so far I have not tested.